# Which of the following efficiency functions belong to O(n3)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I am puzzled about the correct answer here:

> Which of the following efficiency functions belong to O(n<sup>3</sup>)?
>
> (a) 2n<sup>2</sup>+10n+100
>   (b) 3n<sup>3</sup>+9
>   (c) n+100
>   (d) 5n<sup>3</sup>+2n<sup>2</sup>+4n+1
>
> Answers:
>
> ✅ all of them
>        (b) and (d)
>        (a) and (c)
>        none

How option a and c are also correct?

Comment: We just take the highest exponent from the equation and discard the rest, as well as any constants. `O(7n)` is just `O(n)`. And `O(7n^2 +6n)` is just `O(n^2)`

Comment: (c) is the only one that's O(n). Both (a) and (c) are O(n^2). All of them are O(n^3). All of them are O(n^4). Big-O is any function that grows as fast or faster than the given function. It's not a tight upper bound, it's just an upper bound.

Comment: Please, do not post images of text. Type the text and use the formatting options available.

Comment: Take the mathematical definition of big O, and see how it applies in cases a and c. Most beginner problems with big O tend to be the application of rules of thumb that are only partially correct rather than relying on the actual definition.

Answer (score 2):

The key fact you need to answering this question, is that big O gives an *upper bound*, not necessarily a *tight* bound.

So for example *f*(*n*) = *n* belongs to O(*n*), but also to O(*n*<sup>100</sup>).

There is also another notion, called big Theta, which is probably what you had in mind. See the list of notations on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations):

> - *f*(*n*) = O(*g*(*n*))   |   Big O         |     |*f*| is bounded above by *g* (up to constant factor) asymptotically
> - *f*(*n*) = Θ(*g*(*n*))   |     Big Theta    |      *f* is bounded both above and below by *g* asymptotically

If the question would have been *"which functions belong to Θ(n<sup>3</sup>)"*, then indeed only answer "(b) and (d)" would have been correct.